# My baby girl is 12 months old

Tags: behavior, food

She is eating only blended food she can not eat solid food without blend and that make me very sad to see my baby not gaining proper weight for her age. Now she is 9 kg. Please help me what should I do to introduce her for solid food without blend. Other than that she also not interest sometimes even for blended food she try to vomit. Please can you help me ?

Comment: Hi and welcome to Parenting.SE! Please take the [tour](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/tour) and read the [help center](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). Did you already see a doctor?

Comment: Have you tried not blending the food quite as much? Leave it a little chunky and gradually make it more solid.

Comment: Have you tried giving her cucumber or strawberries to suck on? (good for teething too). I've seen products that have a baby handle and a net for the food, if you're worried about accidental choking.

Comment: Weight seems OK. Is she losing weight? What kinds of solids have you tried? Try foods she can hold and feed to herself to introduce things.

Comment: This question is similar and answers may be helpful, but I feel it's slightly different because that focuses on a child with little interest in eating, rather than the gagging/vomiting aspect https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/2452/how-can-i-switch-an-exclusively-breastfed-1-year-old-to-food?rq=1

Answer (score 2):

Some degree of gagging, even occasional vomiting is normal in a child who is learning to eat solid foods. The baby's gag reflex is more sensitive and farther forward than an adults.  It becomes less so as a child grows, through a combination of time/maturing and the process of experiencing food texture and learning how to take an appropriate size bite of food, chew and manipulate food with the mouth and tongue.

In general, it's okay if a child under one doesn't get a lot of nutrition from solid foods.  Milk/Formula supply a large component of the baby's calories and nutrition until one year of age, but the exact timing can vary from one child to the next.  You shouldn't be forcing her to eat against her will at this age, as it can foster a bad relationship with food that could make feeding during her toddler years a real difficulty.

There are a few things you can try:

Gradually increase the thickness and chunkiness of her blended food to get her used to more texture.

Try to make meals pleasant and stress-free.  Don't feed her if she's unwilling or turns her face away.  Have her eat with the rest of the family to learn by watching and try to make it a happy and social occasion.

Offer her finger foods, teething biscuits, fruit, small bits of whatever the family is eating, etc.  She will probably mostly play with these at first if she is accustomed to being spoon fed, but in the course of time she should begin to feed herself.  Offer her utensils to use, but don't fret if she only uses her hands.  Touching and playing with the food is a valuable part of becoming accustomed to different textures.

If you feel that she is not improving her eating skills, or she loses weight, or if you are very concerned, consider asking her doctor to a referral to feeding therapy.  This kind of treatment can be helpful for children with major food aversions, difficulty swallowing, or other medical reasons for eating problems.

Answer (score 0):

Hi highly recommend researching a method called **Baby Led Weaning**. There are books on this topic as well as some extremely helpful facebook groups.

We did this with our daughter and she has been self-feeding and and eating solids since 6 months old.  But PLEASE research the method first before going in to it.  Learning the difference between gagging and chocking is extremely important, as are food sizes, shapes and consistencies.

Here are some resources:

Facebook Group: [Baby Led Weaning for Beginners](https://www.facebook.com/groups/1578341132430270/)

Book: [Baby Led Weaning](https://www.amazon.ca/Baby-Led-Weaning-Essential-Introducing-Foods/dp/161519021X/ref=asc_df_161519021X/?tag=googleshopc0c-20&linkCode=df0&hvadid=292938022932&hvpos=1o1&hvnetw=g&hvrand=16086598841628778900&hvpone=&hvptwo=&hvqmt=&hvdev=c&hvdvcmdl=&hvlocint=&hvlocphy=9001598&hvtargid=pla-432730856779&psc=1)

Our daughter eats what we eat - no preparing separate meals for her. We've never made or given her purees.  When we go out for dinner, we don't even have to order her her own meal - she eats bits of ours.  Best of luck to you!