# How much should we be feeding a 13month old?

Tags: toddler, food

We have the opposite problem to many people at this age.  Rather than having a fussy eater W will eat anything and everything put in front of him.

Whilst that in itself isn't a problem, the, let's say, "End Results" are.

Nappies are very full and the results loose, but not loose enough to be of alarm.

It's possible that there is a food sensitivity, but first up we think that we're likely overfeeding him.  He's tall for age, but slim (50%) much like his parents.

How much, and of what balance should we be feeding him?

Comment: [Marie's answer to this question](http://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/2444/how-should-i-deal-with-my-toddlers-difficult-behavior-towards-food) may be helpful to you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, apparently most 13-month olds are really picky about their food. So hey, you have that blessing, at least.

[BabyCenter](http://www.babycenter.com/6_your-13-month-old_5906.bc) suggests keeping meals balanced:

> Keep offering a variety of healthy foods at every meal. Resist the temptation to let him snack on sweets and other not-so-healthy items out of worry that he's not eating enough. As long as he appears to be thriving, he's probably fine.

[What to Expect](http://www.whattoexpect.com/toddler/eating-basics/what-to-serve.aspx) offer this advice:

> - Find toddler foods that multitask.
> - Make drinks for toddlers for real.
> - Snack wisely.
> - Go for quality over quantity.
> - Change things up.
> - Ditch the distractions.
> - Look at the big picture.
> - Get the facts on fats.

They also suggestion [introducing a variety of veggies](http://www.whattoexpect.com/toddler/eating-basics/go-for-the-green.aspx) into his diet. Actually, What to Expect has a [whole section](http://www.whattoexpect.com/toddler/eating-basics.aspx) on toddler eating basics, as well as a a [road map](http://www.whattoexpect.com/toddler-eating-and-nutrition-tips.aspx) to his feeding through to his second birthday.

That said, What to Expect also points out that a toddler's stomach holds 2 cups of food max, which is rougly [half the size of an adult stomach](http://hypertextbook.com/facts/2000/JonathanCheng.shtml). Be mindful of this when you feed your wee one. Also, if he is, uhh, finishing out "loose," maybe cut back on the fiber some? Otherwise, as long as you're staying balanced, and things don't seem wrong in the, uh, aftermath, I think it should be okay.

One note: if he's really that loose, make sure he's [staying hydrated](http://www.webmd.com/digestive-disorders/diarrhea-directory).

Comment: We're happy about what were feeding being healthy. It's the quantity that we're most unsure of. And how much of what per day. Will cut ack on fibre andvseevwhat happens